# PHP foreach loop creating issue in chrome and go into infinite stage

Tags: php

I have an issue with Google chrome browser, below are the PHP code to calculate shipping prices, this code is working fine in all browser but in Goggle chrome it go to infinite loop.

When check in developer tools then see multiple network requests with status cancelled.

```
foreach($ShippingArray['method'] as $m => $arr) {
    foreach($arr['rates'] as $rateArr) {
        $code = $m.'__'.$rateArr['code'];
        if(isset($PostArray['ship_method']) && $code == $PostArray['ship_method']) {
            $Obj->Total = (float)$Obj->Total + (float)$rateArr['price'];
            $CalArray['shipping'] = [
                "display"      => "1",
                //"title"      => "Shipping (".$arr['title']."-".$rateArr['title'].")",
                "title"        => "Shipping (".$rateArr['title'].")",
                "code"         => $code,
                "price"        => $rateArr['price'],
                "displayprice" => $CurrencyObj->Change2CurrentCurrency($rateArr['price']),
            ];  
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The error doesn't come from PHP - this is a server language - but from how you call it.

Comment: Chrome has nothing to do with the PHP code. PHP runs on the server and just returns HTML to the browser

Comment: I guess this code is called through AJAX, or at least from javascript, and this is causing the crash.

Comment: Apart from PHP being browser-independant, `foreach` loops can never turn infinite - they either run out of elements to iterate over or out of memory to add more elements.

Comment: Try testing for $arr['rates'] before using it, is it valid?  Does it have a code?

Comment: Hi Sunil. As others have said, it is very unlikely that this has anything to do with your PHP code. It is much more likely to be something in your client-side Javascript. If the request status is `cancelled`, it could well be a same-origin/CORS problem, or something similar. You should probably look at that  part of your code rather than the server-side part.